# How to populate a textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, populate

I have a gridview that contais a textbox in row 0.

I am able to read the textbox with this two instructions:

```
Dim control As Control = gridview.Rows(0).FindControl("textbox")
Dim valueInTextbox As TextBox = CType(cntrol, TextBox)
```

My question is, how can I send data to textbox, for example sent the letter "A" to the textbox?. Any suggestion?

I am using this line to try to populate the textbox but my textbox disappear:

```
gridview.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text = "A"
```

Thanks.

Comment: `valueInTextbox.Text = "A"` start with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the text using the following lines:

```
Dim control As Control = gridview.Rows(0).FindControl("textbox")
If control IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim valueInTextbox As TextBox = CType(cntrol, TextBox)
    valueInTextbox.Text = "Some Text"
End If
```